# Error in log(n) : non-numeric argument to mathematical function

Tags: r, distribution

I am trying to estimate the parameters of Burr distribution. The procedure is supposed to be pretty easy. I derived and coded a log likelihood function and I'm using a "maxLik" function for estimation.

From the error message I understand that `log(n)` probably gets char or NaN value and that's why return an error back, but it doesn't really help. I checked the code several times. It should work. If I change the loglik function (say, I'm using loglik from Laplace distribution with one parameter), then the code works. So, I assume it's something wrong with the way I defined the loglik function.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
y = c(rep(Mean.Income,Number))
N=length(y)
logLik = function(m,n,k)
{
    ll = N*(log(m)+log(n)+log(k)) - (k+1)*sum(log(1+m*y^n)) + (n-1)*sum(y)
    return (ll)
} 


estimate = maxLik(logLik,start=c(0.1, 0.1, 0.1), print.level=2, method="NR", grad=NULL, hess=NULL)
```

y - income data. It consists of the income and the number of households, who get this income. Can it be the problem of big numbers? I have about 3000 observations, income varies 5,000-400,000 and number of occurrence (Number variable) varies from 4 to 8530. 
Also, I feel like there can be a problem with this part `log(1+m*y^n)`, because `y` is a vector and `m, n` are numbers.

When I check the function by itself, it works. For example:

```
> logLik(1,5,0.1)
[1] 2560797466
```

I will highly appreciate any hints on what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Function like this do not pass function parameters for each value you are estimating, instead they pass one vector with all the values and you must choose the element you want. If you pass a named vector as your start value, it will be easier to track your estimates. For example

```
y <- c(rep(rpois(20,500),sample(2:7, 20, replace=T)))
N <- length(y)

logLik = function(x) {
    m <- x["m"]; n <- x["n"]; k <- x["k"]
    ll = N*(log(m)+log(n)+log(k)) - (k+1)*sum(log(1+m*y^n)) + (n-1)*sum(y)
    return (ll)
} 

library(maxLik)
estimate = maxLik(logLik,start=c(m=0.1, n=0.1, k=0.1), print.level=2, 
    method="NR", grad=NULL, hess=NULL)
```

This will at least fix the error you were getting. It was caused because the parameters `n` and `k` were never set and were missing

Comment: I see what you mean. And yes, you're right, that has fixed the problem. Thank you!